# Some properties of Polish space

Tags: general-topology, axiom-of-choice

Let $X$ be a separable complete metric space.

I wonder if following properties hold in ZF.

1. Limit Compact ⇒ Compact
2. Does there exist a function$f$ such that $f(E)$ is closed and $f(E)\subset E$, for every infinite set $E$ in $X$.

If 2 doesn't hold, what if $E$ is Dedekind-Infinite?

It seems if 2 holds, 1 holds immediately.
(See [Constructing a choice function in a complete & separable metric space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/209360/constructing-a-choice-function-in-a-complete-separable-metric-space).)

Comment: There are two non-equivalent definitions for Tarski-finite sets. Which one are you using?

Comment: @Asaf I don't know about Tarski-finite sets, but i'm referring Tarski-infinite set to a set of which cardinal is not smaller than $\aleph_0$.

Comment: When we have a definition for $X$-finite, then we say that $A$ is $X$-infinite if it is *not* $X$-finite. So it is equivalent to ask how do you define finiteness. Either way, you should have just said an *infinite* set, this is the common interpretation of the term; whereas Tarski-infinite (especially in the context of AC) could mean a set that has a chain of subsets which is unbounded.

Comment: Also, note that in a metric space every singleton is closed, so (2) holds trivially since $E$ is non-empty.

Comment: The [third] edit is still trivial; take a constant function.

Comment: @Asaf Thank you for the advice. Please let me know if it's still trivial.

Comment: Maybe you want "$E$ is infinite then it has an infinite closed subset"?

Comment: @Asaf It doesn't have to. I want to know that if there exists a choice function in a polish space. Even if $f(E)$ is finite, it's fine.

Comment: But it's unclear how you wish to quantify this. Do you want a single $f$ which gives that out; or for every $E$ you want to find some $f$ which does that?

Comment: If one can formulate a closed subset for a given arbitrary $E$, doesn't this mean that "there exists a function $f$ such that $f(E)$ is a closed subset of $E$, for every infinite set $E$ in$X$"?

Comment: But do you want $\forall E\exists f$? This is trivially true. You could want $\exists f\forall E$ which requires some choice

Comment: @Asaf I got it. I hope my final edit is fine :)

Answer (score 1):

The second answer is "no".

Consider a model in which there is an infinite Dedekind-finite set of real numbers, now consider all its subsets which are infinite.

We observe that every closed subset of a D-finite set is finite. (Not relatively closed, but really closed.) We also observe that we can always choose from finite sets of real numbers, since those are well-ordered by the natural order of the reals (every linear order on a finite set is a well-order). Therefore the existence of such $f$ implies that we can choose a point from every subset of our D-finite set, which means it is well-orderable, which means it is finite. Contradiction.

Comment: I believe the requirement that $E$ is D-infinite is still not enough, but I will have to think about it some more.

Comment: If it's not true for D-infinite, what's the reason you think that makes it not possible? Choosing Countable subsets from D-infinite sets? Or Choosing Well-orderings of Countable sets? I would like to know how you think about 'existence of such function whose domain is a collection of Countable sets'

Comment: @Katlus: Choosing a well-ordering. For example it is consistent that there is no choice of well-ordering for every countable set of real numbers, so the set $\{A\subseteq\mathbb R\mid A\text{ is countably infinite}\}$ has a cardinality strictly larger than $\mathbb R$.